# Google play games services - launching the google+ sign in flow from an app in landscape mode

Tags: android, google-plus, landscape, landscape-portrait, google-play-games

Let me start with the relevant code from the GameHelper class found in [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils), provided by the google team as a starting point:

```
 /**
 * Attempts to resolve a connection failure. This will usually involve
 * starting a UI flow that lets the user give the appropriate consents
 * necessary for sign-in to work.
 */
synchronized void resolveConnectionResult() {

    // Try to resolve the problem
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        // This problem can be fixed. So let's try to fix it.
        try {
            // launch appropriate UI flow (which might, for example, be the
            // sign-in flow)
            mExpectingActivityResult = true;

 // >>> **I 'VE ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE - IT RESOLVES MY ISSUE WITH SOME SIDE EFFECTS which are irrelevant with the problem here (they have to do with my app)** <<<
            mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, RC_RESOLVE);                
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            ...
        }
    } else {
           ....
    }
}
```

My application's manifest file forces the orientation of my app to landscape

```
  android:configChanges="orientation"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

When my player requests a multi-player game for the first time, he is presented with the google+ sign-in button, drawn in an opengl canvas (everything in landscape). As soon as he taps it, the user initiated sign-in flow begins and the above method is executed.

**If I comment out the line that I 've added half-way, strange things happen.**

Sometimes I am presented with the dialogue to chose one of my google accounts, some other times the result of the intent indicates failure to connect and I return to my app.
For these times that I am able to choose an account, after I do so:

- The orientation of the screen goes back and forth from landscape to portrait a couple of times
- The activity that presents google's sign-in dialogue is launched many times on-top of itself.
- I have to select my google+ app sharing preferences and press "OK" at least 3 times in at least 3 successive identical dialogues. Sometimes the "public" button is missing (there is white-space in its position)
- Sometimes I successfully sign-in in after all the above happen, some other times I get a failure message. When I click sign-in again, it automatically signs in successfully without any user interaction.

I am trying to figure out whether I am doing something wrong, or if this is a known issue. Is anyone able to reproduce it? (note that this happens **only on the first sign-in**, i.e. if one wants to try and reproduce it he will first need to:

- Clear the app data
- Go to the google+ app settings, and disconnect the app from the google account

I am not sure whether this has to do with connecting to the GAMES_CLIENT, or if launching the google+ sign-in flow from a landscape app is problematic in general.

Thanks in advance,
Nikos

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I'll try to repro this and get back to this question once I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. When I set up my test app exactly as you described and hold my phone in landscape orientation, no problem happens. When I hold the phone in portrait orientation, I can see the orientation changing as the sign-in dialogs appear, and then it changes back to landscape when the app regains focus, but everything seems to be working. The auth and consent dialog appear only once, and everything seems to work fine.

That said, my sample doesn't use an OpenGL canvas -- maybe that's where the problem is. Might be some weird interaction between the canvas and the sign-in flow. I would recommend hiding the OpenGL surface (and replace it with a static View that says "Signing in...") while you go through the sign-in flow, just to be sure.

Comment: your help is very much appreciated. :) Indeed hiding the opengl surface works - I 'll stick with that for now!